# Connecting to HIve JDBC through R Class Error

Tags: r, jdbc, hive

I am trying to connect to hive using R JDBC library. My code looks like this:

```
library('DBI')
library('rJava')
library('RJDBC')

hadoop.class.path = list.files(path=c('/usr/hdp/hadoop/'), pattern='jar', full.names=T);
hadoop.lib.path = list.files(path=c('/usr/hdp/hadoop/lib/'), pattern='jar', full.names=T);
hive.class.path = list.files(path=c('/usr/hdp/hive/lib/'), pattern='jar', full.names=T);
mapred.class.path = list.files(path=c('/usr/hdp/hadoop-mapreduce'), pattern='jar', full.names=T);
cp = c(hadoop.class.path, hadoop.lib.path, hive.class.path, mapred.class.path, '/usr/hdp/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core.jar')
.jinit(classpath=cp)

drv <- JDBC('org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver', '/usr/hdp/hive/lib/hive-jdbc.jar')
con <- dbConnect(drv, 'jdbc:hive2://my.cluster.net:10000/default;principal=hive/my.cluster.net@domain.com', 'hive', 'hive')
```

But when I run, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil
```

However, I checked my /usr/hdp/hadoop/hadoop-commons.jar and found that the class org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil is there. So what else could be causing this error?

Comment: I guess the error reads to "could not instantiate SecurityUtil because *some other* class could not be found. Any way to get more Exception output?

Comment: Gotcha, I thought it was implying SecurityUtil was missing. I solved my problem by just installing the cloudera driver. It had all the right jars in there. You can use the driver even if you don't have cloudera apparently. https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/connectors/hive/jdbc/2-5-4.html